# Is it possible to use if statement in Bootstrap's different screen size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, stylus

I use Stylus and Bootstrap 3, and want to set my blog's padding property with respective to different screen size, so I wrote the following:

```
.blog
    margin-bottom: 20px
    if @screen-sm-min
        margin-bottom: 10px
```

However, even when I ran my app, it didn't change at all. I'm not sure what's wrong with my syntax. Why does this not work well? How to solve the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Saying:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .. add some styles here...
}
```

Is the same as saying:

```
if (the minimum width of the screen is 1000px && the maximum width of the screen is 1200px) {
  .. add some styles here .. 
}
```

Comment: Does this code work in Stylus? Or do I have to write it in plain CSS? I tried to write in Stylus some code like (`@media(min-width: @screen-sm-min) background-color: black` and then `@media(min-width: @screen-lg-min) background-color: red`) but it didn't change at all...

Comment: Ah, I found that my resultant CSS file doesn't interpret `@screen-lg-min` variable, probably because my Stylus file cannot refer to the Bootstrap variable. Then I wonder, does the above media query setting written in the HTML file?

Comment: Well, you could definitely still use the media query I provided to get the correct breakpoints you're looking for in any CSS file - or in a <style> element within an HTML file.  Just modify the values of min-width and max-width.  I've never used stylus though.  As far as I know, Bootstrap is built with LESS modules not Stylus.  Looks like Stylus's media queriy syntax can be found at this url, though: http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/media.html

Comment: I just found the module too, but since the project I'm developing is pretty small and I don't plan to use any other media query settings, I would decide to just write it in my HTML file. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Oops. It's different from what I found. My bad. I was talking about [this module](https://github.com/Acquisio/bootstrap-stylus)

Answer (score 0):

What you should read about is responsive design-media queries.
You can read this for example: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/

but simple google search for responsive design will give you many results.